# R: Reducing data frame to rows that fully match across two columns

Tags: r

This may be a repeat, but I've used all sorts of different keywords trying to find an answer to this and have failed. What I want to do is remove all instances of non-matches across multiple columns from a data frame:

```
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5)
type = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a")
df = data.frame(id,type)


   id type

1   1    a
2   1    a
3   1    b
4   2    b
5   2    b
6   3    a
7   3    b
8   4    b
9   5    a
10  5    a
```

In this case, I want to only keep the rows that are full matches across each ID, so my output should be

```
    id type
4   2    b
5   2    b
8   4    b 
9   5    a
10  5    a
```

Thanks in advance to anybody that can help me out here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your `ids` are complete and sequential, this should work nicely only using base R:

```
ids = which(tapply(df$type, df$id, function(x) length(unique(x))==1)
subset(df, id %in% ids)
```

If they are not, this should work in its place:

```
ids = unique(df$id)[which(tapply(df$type, df$id, function(x) length(unique(x))==1)]
```

I tend to prefer `data.table` for these situations:

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,if(length(unique(type))==1) .SD, by=id]
```

Comment: yep, this will do it! i knew there had to be a straight forward way to do this but i just couldn't find it. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An `ave` alternative:

```
df[ave(as.numeric(df$type), df$id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one with `plyr` , but the `data.table` solution is certainly more elegant :

```
ddply(df, "id", function(d) {
    if (identical(levels(factor(d$type)),levels(df$type))) NULL else d
})
```

Comment: thanks for this, i really do need to learn how to use plyr more effectively!